# How to control an input element's selection range?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

How do I properly control an input element's selection? Similar to how we control an input's value by setting the `value` and `onChange` attributes, is it possible to do the same for the selection of the text when it's focused? Here's my first attempt:

```jsx
function Input() {
  const inputRef = useRef(null);
  const [selection, setSelection] = useState({ start: 0, end: 0 });

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    inputRef.current.setSelectionRange(selection.start, selection.end);
  }, [selection.start, selection.end]);

  return (
    <input
      ref={inputRef}
      onSelect={(e) => {
        setSelection({
          start: e.currentTarget.selectionStart || 0,
          end: e.currentTarget.selectionEnd || 0,
        });
      }}
    />
  );
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4oc69yps/7/)

The only problem is that when I type some characters and then press <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>LEFT ARROW</kbd> multiple times to select to the left, it appears to shift the end of the selection to the left on every other key press.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you do not precise the [direction](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/setSelectionRange) of the selection.

This can be fixed by adding those two lines to your code:

- In the `onSelect`:
  `direction: e.currentTarget.selectionDirection || 'forward',`
- In the `useLayoutEffect`
  `inputRef.current.setSelectionRange(selection.start, selection.end, selection.direction);`

```
const Input = () => {
  const inputRef = React.useRef(null);
  const [selection, setSelection] = React.useState({ start: 0, end: 0, direction:'forward' });

  React.useLayoutEffect(() => {
    inputRef.current.setSelectionRange(selection.start, selection.end, selection.direction);
  }, [selection.start, selection.end, selection.direction]);

  return (
    <input
      ref={inputRef}
      onSelect={(e) => {
        setSelection({
          start: e.currentTarget.selectionStart || 0,
          end: e.currentTarget.selectionEnd || 0,
          direction: e.currentTarget.selectionDirection || 'forward',
        });
      }}
    />
  );
}
```